# Is it possible to use the IN opertator for couples in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table named "elevation" with the following columns:

- lat: double (key)
- long: double (key)
- value: double

When I use the following syntax, I get a "row value misused" error.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM elevation
WHERE (lat, long) IN ((29.42682, 81.774118), (29.63561, 81.622355))
```

While this syntax works:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM elevation
WHERE (lat, long) = (29.42682, 81.774118) OR (lat, long) = (29.63561, 81.622355)
```

Does this mean that the IN operator can't be used on couples?

Comment: Yes. The first syntax doesn't work and the second one works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn) and [C Perkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1261752/c-perkins). I'll summarize your answers here (tell me if I made a mistake).

So there is two ways to do this.

The "elegant way" ([Shawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907459/is-it-possible-to-use-the-in-opertator-for-couples-in-sqlite/56908985#56908985)):
It uses the VALUES keyword.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM elevation
WHERE (lat, long) IN (VALUES (29.42682, 81.774118), (29.63561, 81.622355));
```

And the optimized way ([C Perkins's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56908852/9515617)), usefull when there is a lot of data to query:
It uses a temporary table.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coordinates (lat, long);
DELETE FROM coordinates;
INSERT INTO coordinates VALUES (29.42682, 81.774118), (29.63561, 81.622355);
SELECT *
FROM elevation
WHERE (lat, long) IN coordinates;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just have a few coordinates, you can use them directly with `IN` instead of using a temp table (But if you have lots, that approach is better especially with the index on the table). You were so, so close with your attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM elevation
WHERE (lat, long) IN (VALUES (29.42682, 81.774118), (29.63561, 81.622355));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, the `IN` operator can be used with couples on the left-hand side.  More generally, the left-hand side can be a row value with multiple columns.  See https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html.

An alternative to typing out a repetitive list of OR statements is to create a temporary table with the list of literal values that can be "queried" in a subquery expression.  Indexes can also be added to the temp table to make it more efficient.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coordinates (lat, long, UNIQUE (lat, long));
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO coordinates VALUES (29.42682, 81.774118), (29.63561, 81.622355);
SELECT *
FROM elevation
WHERE (lat, long) IN coordinates;
```

Notice the shorter reference since the temp table contains the same number of fields.  One could use the more verbose `WHERE (lat, long) IN (SELECT * FROM coordinates)`, but that's not necessary here.

Comment: I corrected my answer since Shawn revealed that literal table rows can be specified, but kept it since the other answers refer to this.